# JavaScript array order on decimal numbers not correct after sort()

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

Can someone explain to me why this code below:

```
var points = [
  99.1,
  100,
  99.9
];

console.log(points.sort());
```

...`log()`s this, unsorted array:

```
[100, 99.1, 99.9]
```

After `sort()`, shouldn't the array be this below?

```
[100, 99.9, 99.1]
```

Comment: Why would you think that `99.9` would come before `99.1`?

Comment: I guess OP expected it to be sorted numerically descending.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From w3schools:

> By default, the sort() method sorts the values as strings in
>   alphabetical and ascending order.
>
> This works well for strings ("Apple" comes before "Banana"). However,
>   if numbers are sorted as strings, "25" is bigger than "100", because
>   "2" is bigger than "1".
>
> Because of this, the sort() method will produce an incorrect result
>   when sorting numbers.

You can fix this by providing a "compare function".

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_sort.asp

Comment: It is nice explained here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

Comment: Yes, `sort` by default will sort `100` before `99`, but that is not what the OP is asking. He is wondering why it sorts `99.1` before `99.9`, and the answer is, well, that's the correct sort order even with a string comparison.